# Havok Physics Engine - Android

Tags: android, ios, physics, havok

Can anyone guide me where I can find tutorial on how to use Havok Physics Engine with Android/iOS?

Hope this is not a completely dumb question but I couldn't find any tutorial or help...

Comment: Start by going to http://www.havok.com/ and then ask their sales team if Havok can run on Android/iOS. Then buy a license to get the documentation needed if so.

Comment: Thanks. I went to the website and downloading the SDK. Yes, it works on Android/iOS (Sony and recent Facebook Home) are already using it. It is also specified on their website. I am need to know if someone can fastern my learning process... I am trying with NDK on andorid at the moment and for iOS I can directly access as a C++ library

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I should add the following:

The Havok team is currently working on a (free, although there's a mention of 'flexible licensing models') mobile game engine called [Project Anarchy](http://www.projectanarchy.com/), which should become available this spring and will initially support iO, Android and PlayStation Vita - Windows 8 support is 'coming soon'. And yes, it includes Havok Physics.

According to the [Havok website](http://www.havok.com/solutions/mobile-game-developers) Project Anarchy will come with:

- Comprehensive game samples and tutorials to get started
- Online community support with forums, Q&A and videos

Could be worth having a look into once it's been launched.

Comment: Thanks MH. Helps a lot. I also found this discussion forum on itel site where many havok questions are listed.. Right now going through them to see if I can find helpful things. I will post it here if I do.

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: I work for Havok)

The free version of Havok Physics (http://software.intel.com/sites/havok/en/) only works on Windows and it's only the 32bit version. You can get help from the Havok forums here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/havok/
There are also some training videos to get you up and running with Havok Physics available here: http://www.youtube.com/user/HavokEnthusiast

However, Havok will soon be releasing a cross-platform engine called **Project Anarchy** that will be free for both iOS and Android. It will include Havok **Physics**, Havok **Animation Studio**, and Havok **AI** all bundled together. For more information and to sign up to the newsletter go here: http://www.projectanarchy.com/

Comment: Reconfirms what MH said. Thanks for the info. I will look forward to that.